# How can I change the language (to english) in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: configuration, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running a non-english Windows 7 system, and apparently Oracle SQL Developer (version 3.0.04.34, 64-bit) tries to auto-guess my preferred language based on the OS. Is there any way to change the language to english?

I've tried the tip found at http://misteratmisis.com/infotech/how-change-oracle-sql-developer-interface-japanese-english, namely adding the VM options

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
AddVMOption -Duser.country=US
```

to file ide.conf in directory

```
/ide/bin
```

within the SQL Developer installation directory, as suggested, but that didn't help.

**Solution (edited on 13.09.2012):**

I decided to try again the solution proposed by Alex K. and this time it worked, namely adding

```
AddVMOption  -Duser.language=en
```

to the file `sqldeveloper.conf` file located in `sqldeveloper\bin\` folder. I presume that it did work now but not before, because meanwhile I have changed my UAC (user access control) settings in Windows 7 so that I am administrator by default. What happened before was probably that even though the changes appeared to be there, the configuration file read by the program was another one (shadow copy).

**Solution for Mac OS X (added on 26.02.2016):**

Edit file at

`/Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf`

and add the line

```
AddVMOption  -Duser.language=en
```

(Tested with SQL Developer 4.1.3.20)

Comment: Apparently somebody voted to close this as off-topic. I considered briefly asking this at superuser.com, but as Oracle SQL Developer is a tool primarily used by developers I think this question is most relevant here. As stated in SO FAQ, questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" should be welcome on SO, so I can't imagine this question being off-topic. However, if this question could be improved I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: it worked like a breeze! simon you are da man!

Comment: Adding: AddVMOption -Duser.language=en to file: /ide/bin did not work for me either **until I started sqldeveloper with administrator rights.**

Comment: If you are limited by missing admin privileges, go for the solution from @anilech .
I have similar problems and created a .bat file calling `sqldeveloper.exe --AddVMOption=-Duser.language=en`

Comment: If you are not the admin and need a workaround, besides creating a .bat, you may also modify your windows shortcut by adding the extra option.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Try to set ***`user.language`*** and ***`user.country`*** properties in ***`sqldeveloper.conf`*** file located in *sqldeveloper\bin* folder (*`%APPDATA%\sqldeveloper\<version>\product.conf`* for more recent versions) .
Sample for set ***french*** language:

```
IncludeConfFile ../../ide/bin/ide.conf

SetJavaHome D:\jdk1.6.0_25

AddVMOption  -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true

AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false

AddVMOption -Dwindows.shell.font.languages=
AddVMOption -Duser.language=fr
AddVMOption -Duser.country=FR
AddVMOption  -XX:MaxPermSize=128M

AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false  
IncludeConfFile  sqldeveloper-nondebug.conf
```

To switch off language try to remove its support by editing ***`oracle.translated.locales`***  option in ***`ide.boot`*** file (located in ide\bin folder).
For example, if I want to 'break' ***french*** language support this option will be:

```
oracle.translated.locales = de,es,it,ja,ko,pt_BR,zh_CN,zh_TW
```

The original value was:

```
oracle.translated.locales = de,fr,es,it,ja,ko,pt_BR,zh_CN,zh_TW
```

The configuration above (sqldeveloper.conf file) will be wrong after remove ***french*** support and the ***french*** language does not appear as GUI localization.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In your case the language is possibly english because there is no russian language support for the program and it falls back to english?

Comment: Did you download localization (non-english)? I can try to change language

Comment: No, I just downloaded the standard version from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Comment: Ok, I'll try to set french language

Comment: I've just successfully set french language for gui, but russian doesn't work

Comment: I've just add info to my answer. Please, try to do the same

Comment: I tried setting the user.language and user.country properties exactly as you did (tested also with en/EN) but the language did not change from German to French or English. Possibly the problem lies within Windows 7 - AFAIK Win7 sometimes makes "shadow" copies of some configuration files, hiding the changes made by the user to configuration files.

Comment: I'm using Win7 too. Oracle SQL Developer seems to be portable application, you can try to start it from another folder. Did you try to reboot OS?

Comment: I rebooted the OS, still no change. This is really a mystery.. :/

Comment: May be some of your config files already has the same options and override this new ones? You can check both installation folder and application data folder.

Comment: I checked everything in C:\Users\simon\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer but no conflicting settings were found. I even searched for "language" in every file and checked all the settings, but no odd results. I made the same search in C:\Program Files (x86)\sqldeveloper64-3.0.04.34-no-jre, no conflicting settings there either. I'm starting to give up..

Comment: @simon I've just find another solution )))

Comment: For recent versions, the recommend place to add the option seems to be  "%APPDATA%\sqldeveloper\<version>\product.conf".

Comment: If you're using SQL Developer on Linux, the configuration file is located in: ~/.sqldeveloper/18.4.0/product.conf

Answer (score 86):

You can also set language at runtime

```
sqldeveloper.exe --AddVMOption=-Duser.language=en
```

to avoid editing sqldeveloper.conf every time you install new version.

Comment: As someone who works on Korean systems all the time, thank you. This is a much better alternative to switching the default setup.

Comment: Thanks, I picked this answer considering it was the easiest for me to change, and it suits me well.

Comment: +1 for nice solution, even useful for users without admin privileges and having pre-installed SW on Company Computers and don't want to consider it whenever a new version gets installed.

Comment: It was the best option to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 54):

You can also configure directly on the file `..sqldeveloper\ide\bin\ide.conf`:

Just add the JVM Option:

> AddVMOption  -Duser.language=en

The file will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Solved the language setting successfully by your approach!!

Answer (score 7):

Or use the menu: **Tools**->**Preferences**->**Database**->**NLS** and change language and territory.
[image]

Comment: doesn't change the application's language for me

Comment: Actually this time it didn't work for me neither (v20.2)

Comment: These are just database NLS settings, which controls how database behaves on error messages etc. It doesn't have anything to do with the applications language!
This tab is similar to setting environment variable (e.g. for sqlplus) to NLS_LANG=EN_SP

Answer (score 6):

With SQL Developer 4.x, the language option is to be added to `..\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf`, rather than `..\sqldeveloper\bin\ide.conf`:

```
# ----- MODIFICATION BEGIN -----
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
# ----- MODIFICATION END -----
```

Comment: I can't agree with you. I'm using SQL Developer 4.1.3. I changed `ide.conf` and worked well.

Comment: @HaozheXie I am on 4.2.0 and `ide.conf` doesn't exist. adding the line in `sqldeveloper.conf` like the answer states worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Before installation use the Control Panel Region and Language Preferences tool to change everything (Format, Keyboard default input, language for non Unicode programs) to English.  Revert to the original selections after the installation.

Answer (score 1):

On MAC High Sierra (10.13.6)

```
cd /Users/vkrishna/.sqldeveloper/18.2.0

nano product.conf
```

on the last line add

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
```

Save the file and restart.

=======================================

If you are using **standalone Oracle Data Modeller**

```
find ~/ -name "datamodeler.conf"
```

and edit this file

```
cd /Users/vkrishna//Desktop/OracleDataModeler-18.2.0.179.0756.app/Contents/Resources/datamodeler/datamodeler/bin/
```

Add somewhere in the last

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en
```

save and restart, done!

Answer (score 1):

+> In Oracle SQL Developer, you can follow steps by steps as the below image:

[image]

+> After opening the file in step 3, you can add this text "AddVMOption -Duser.language=en" to this file and save it.

+> After saving the file, reopen Oracle SQL Developer and check the result.